# Python 3 library to generate client based on wsdl

Tags: python, web-services

I need to generate a python client for wsdl webservice.
I was able to find some libraries to dynamically call soap methods  `service.call('method', param)` but what I need to have is to do 
`service.method(param)` 
so client stubs should be generated into py files so I can have all advantages of auto-completion etc.

I saw some libs like wsdl2py, but looks like all of them are not supported.

Is there any modern lib for it?

Thanks.